# phantomjsdriver title when page not loaded in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-firefoxdriver

In `firefox` when a page is not loading properly we get the "Problem loading page" title, so I can do:

```
driver.get_title()
```

to see if the page has loaded properly.

I'm wondering does `phantomjsdriver` have a title when the page is not loading like `firefox`? If so, any idea what this is?

Comment: What is `driver.get_title()`? Do you mean `driver.title`? It works in a same way for `Firefox` and `PhantomJS`

Comment: ahh lovely thanks Andersson, but I'm wondering do you know what the text of the driver.title will be in PhantomJS - this is "Problem loading page" in firefox. Does it say "Problem loading page" in phantomjs as well?

Comment: No. I think it should be something else, like title of last successfully loaded page